# Phonegap application database version stays after update

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

So if I have a Phonegap application with the line `var db = window.openDatabase("phr", "0.1", "Cognovant PHR", 25000000);` and later on do `db.changeVersion('0.1', '0.2');` how would I have the code dynamically update the "0.1" in the openDatabase call to "0.2" to prevent the application from having to go through the update process each time the user loads the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. So for future reference using the line:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("phr", "", "Cognovant PHR", 25000000);
```

will open the current database without knowing the version. Then you can do:

```
if (db.version != "2") // or whatever version you want to update to
{
    // code to update database
    db.changeVersion(db.version, "2"); //again or whatever version you choose
}
```